# c++ generic programming with templates and nullptr

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming, nullptr

Let's say that I have this generic function:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T data) {
  if(data == nullptr)
   return;
  //...
}
```

The problem is that I can not really write something like that. If T is a primitive type or an object passed by value, I can not compare it with the nullptr.

On the other hand, what if T is a pointer to an int? I would like to be able to compare it with the nullptr.

Is there any way?

Comment: Change the template to `foo(T * data)`.

Comment: I thought about that, but I want both normal values and pointers as T. Maybe what I am asking can not be done(like in Java). The problem is that my compiler accepts a call to foo(nullptr) without complaining if I set T to something like int*. Should it stop me from doing that?

Comment: Do you want `if (data == T{})` ?

Comment: Sorry I do not know the meaning of that expression. I want both class types and pointer types to be boundable to T. The problem is that I can not compare a class type(a value) to nullptr.

Comment: @Kami: It's unclear what you want to do.  (I'm particularly puzzled by why you think the compiler should stop you from calling `foo<int*>(nullptr);` -- why do you think it should stop you?)  If you want 2 versions of `foo()`, one that will take pointer types and test them against `nullptr` and one that will take non-pointer types (and not test them againts `nullptr`), then you can make 2 overloaded function templates.

Comment: Why foo<int*> is possible with a type T? It should be only possible if I wrote T* explicitly(void foo(T *data)...). That was my point.

Comment: What does this function do? (It can handle both integers and pointers?) Why must it reject null pointers?

Comment: I see that there is `std::is_pointer<T>`. You could use that to branch into different code paths depending on the result. But I also like what @Jarod42 suggested. T{} zero-initializes pointers, i.e. results in nullptr, and/or default-initializes other types, depending on what ctors are available.

Comment: @Kami: Based on your last comment, it seems you think that `int*` is not a type -- but it's a type (called "pointer to `int`") in the same category as `int` itself.  A type parameter, like `T` in `template <typename T> ...`, can be replaced with *any* type, including `int*` (or weirder types like `float (int&, char*(*)[42])`, which is the type of a function that takes a reference to `int` and a pointer to an array of 42 pointers to `char`, and returns a `float`), though this may generate downstream errors in the instantiated code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @j_random_hacker suggested, just overload the foo() function. This way you have 2 differents behaviour depending of the type you pass to foo()

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T *data)
{
  if(data == nullptr)
    return;
  //...
}

template<typename T>
void foo(T data)
{
  //...
}
```

Comment: Ok, this is probably the simplest approach.